# Windows Batch File :: Output to Variable when using Pipes

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, pipe

Is it possible to output the result of a command to a variable when using pipes?

Example batch file script:

```
@echo off
cls
echo Script Started
setlocal enableextensions 

::prove that functionality works without pipes
call:OutputCommandToVariable "set computername" demo
echo.%demo%

::prove that the command itself works
call:IsServiceStartAutoDebug "MyComputerName" "wuauserv"

::now try it for real
call:IsServiceStartAuto "MyComputerName" "wuauserv"

::done
goto:end

:IsServiceStartAuto
call:OutputCommandToVariable "sc \\%~1 qc "%~2" | find "START_TYPE" | find "2"" IsServiceStartAuto
echo.%IsServiceStartAuto%
@goto:eof

:OutputCommandToVariable
set "%2="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%~1') do @set "%2=%%a"
::for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`%~1`) do @set "%2=%%a"
@goto:eof

:IsServiceStartAutoDebug
sc \\%~1 qc "%~2" | find "START_TYPE" | find "2"
@goto:eof

:end
Echo Completed
::pause
```

Script Output:

```
Script Started
COMPUTERNAME=MyComputerName
    START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
| was unexpected at this time.
```

Desired Output:

```
Script Started
COMPUTERNAME=MyComputerName
    START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
    START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
Completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:OutputCommandToVariable
SET val=%1
SET val=%val:|=^|%
set "%2="
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%val%) do set "%2=%%a"
::for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`%~1`) do @set "%2=%%a"
goto:eof
```

I'd try these changes, but I can guarantee nothing since whatever the `sc` is doing does nothing apparent on my machine.

The issue is that whereas the string is correctly applied, you need to escape the pipe character within the single-quotes contained between the parentheses in the Court Of King Caractacus.

I did try adding the caret to escape the pipe in the quoted argument to `OutputCommandToVariable` - but it intriguingly gained interest and appeared as a double-caret - possibly batch trying to escape the caret rather than the pipe...

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you - I didn't realise you could do character replacements, nice trick.  FYI: I also had to escape the quotes in the same way as the pipes.  SC is Service Control - you can use it to start/stop/configure windows services.  I use this instead of the NET command since it allows you to control remote machines as well as local.  Thanks again.